# Custom UIView dos not response when added as subview in UIViewController

Tags: swift

there,
I'm trying to separate view(s) code apart from my UIViewController, the displaying part is fine, but won't have any response to user interaction.

For example,
I have my LoginViewController

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {

    let loginView = LoginView(frame: .zero)
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(loginView)
        loginView.centerInSuperview()//extension to center layouts
        loginView.loginButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(loginPressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func loginPressed(sender:UIButton){
         print("login")
    }
}
```

LoginView Class

```
class LoginView: UIView {
    fileprivate let containerWidth:CGFloat = 250
    fileprivate let contentWidth:CGFloat = 240
    let containerView:UIView={
        let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = .white
        v.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        return v
    }()
    let passkeyInput:UITextField = {
        let tf = UITextField(frame: .zero)
        tf.placeholder = "PASSKEY"
        tf.textAlignment = .center
        tf.anchor( size: CGSize(width: 240, height: 0))
        tf.isSecureTextEntry = true
        return tf
    }()
    let loginButton:UIButton={
        let button = UIButton()
        button.backgroundColor = .red
        button.setTitle("LOGIN", for: .normal)
        button.anchor( size: CGSize(width: 240, height: 0))
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        return button
    }()
    func setupView() {
        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [passkeyInput,loginButton])
        stackView.alignment = .center
        stackView.distribution = .equalSpacing
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.spacing = 20
        stackView.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
        stackView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 5, bottom: 10, right: 5)
        addSubview(containerView)
        containerView.addSubview(stackView)
        containerView.anchor(size: CGSize(width: containerWidth, height: 0))//extension to layout
        stackView.fillSuperview()//extension to layout
        containerView.centerInSuperview()//extension to layout
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupView()
    }
}
```

I was expecting to see "login" when click the loginButton, but for some reason, that's not happening.

I've tried a few different things:

So if I put all view code(Code within LoginView) in side the UIViewController, I have no problem see expected result, but that's missing the point -- try to separate view and viewcontroller

And if I change code inside ViewController,
from adding as subview

```
view.addSubview(loginView)
```

to replace existed default view,

```
view = loginView
```

it works for this case, but I'm not always want replacing the view, sometimes(most times) need add subviews

I've tried to search for similar question here, without any success, 
Please help to point out where I did wrong.

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**
This is the layout extension I used, still have not figure out what caused this issue.

```
struct AnchoredConstraints {
    var top, leading, bottom, trailing, width, height: NSLayoutConstraint?
    }

extension UIView {

    @discardableResult
    func anchor(top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil, leading: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil, bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil, trailing: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil, padding: UIEdgeInsets = .zero, size: CGSize = .zero) -> AnchoredConstraints {

        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        var anchoredConstraints = AnchoredConstraints()

        if let top = top {
            anchoredConstraints.top = topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top, constant: padding.top)
        }

        if let leading = leading {
            anchoredConstraints.leading = leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leading, constant: padding.left)
        }

        if let bottom = bottom {
            anchoredConstraints.bottom = bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom, constant: -padding.bottom)
        }

        if let trailing = trailing {
            anchoredConstraints.trailing = trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailing, constant: -padding.right)
        }

        if size.width != 0 {
            anchoredConstraints.width = widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.width)
        }

        if size.height != 0 {
            anchoredConstraints.height = heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.height)
        }

        [anchoredConstraints.top, anchoredConstraints.leading, anchoredConstraints.bottom, anchoredConstraints.trailing, anchoredConstraints.width, anchoredConstraints.height].forEach{ $0?.isActive = true }

        return anchoredConstraints
    }

    func fillSuperview(padding: UIEdgeInsets = .zero) {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        if let superviewTopAnchor = superview?.topAnchor {
            topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superviewTopAnchor, constant: padding.top).isActive = true
        }

        if let superviewBottomAnchor = superview?.bottomAnchor {
            bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superviewBottomAnchor, constant: -padding.bottom).isActive = true
        }

        if let superviewLeadingAnchor = superview?.leadingAnchor {
            leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superviewLeadingAnchor, constant: padding.left).isActive = true
        }

        if let superviewTrailingAnchor = superview?.trailingAnchor {
            trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superviewTrailingAnchor, constant: -padding.right).isActive = true
        }
    }

    func centerInSuperview(size: CGSize = .zero) {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        if let superviewCenterXAnchor = superview?.centerXAnchor {
            centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superviewCenterXAnchor).isActive = true
        }

        if let superviewCenterYAnchor = superview?.centerYAnchor {
            centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superviewCenterYAnchor).isActive = true
        }

        if size.width != 0 {
            widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.width).isActive = true
        }

        if size.height != 0 {
            heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.height).isActive = true
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to give `loginView` a useful frame. `.zero` is not useful.

Comment: @rmaddy, thanks, but I have setup autolayout constraints later part of the code, where I added comment, and https://github.com/bhlvoong/LBTAComponents is the extension I added.

Comment: `isUserInteractionEnabled` true on loginView?

Comment: I believe it's default to enabled, I never disable it. And I tried set it to true again in code and it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: I've tested your code by putting the constraints by myself and everything is working well. Are you sure there is no probs with your autolayout extensions?

Comment: @YannickLoriot Thanks, that's a good point, I never thought about the extension. I stripped out these code to a new project and replaced the layout constraints it seems working fine. Really strange.

Comment: @QiquanLu I've not investigated your lib, but it may misses some constraints?

Comment: @YannickLoriot Not really sure, I updated the question with the layout part, still very strange to me view.addSubview(loginView) shows correct view I'm looking for but without user interaction, but once changed to view = loginView, everything works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button does not trigger the touch event because the `loginView`'s frame is not set. You only defines its position using the `loginView.centerInSuperview()`.

In the `LoginViewController`'s `viewDidLoad()` method add the following code and it should work:

```
loginView.fillSuperview()
```

*(or another frame definition)*

When you use the `view = loginView`, the `frame` is set elsewhere, that's why it's working.

Comment: Thanks Yannick! this is the exact reason, and loginView.fillSuperview() works.

Comment: And your explanation make perfect sense, thanks again